# Liquid conditional rendering

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have blog posts to which I add `tags` in the YFM like this:

`tags: amp`

I want Liquid to check whether the `tag == amp` and if so, to add a link in the `blog-post.html` layout file. I tried the code below:

```
{% if page.tags == "amp" %}
   <a href="#">link</a>
{% endif %}
```

But nothing gets outputted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tags` attribute in the YFM should actually be stored as an array since there can be multiple tags, as seen in the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#categories-and-tags).

```
tags: [amp, foo, bar]
```

When checking the tags, use the [`contains` liquid filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/#contains).

```
{% if page.tags contains 'amp' %}
   <a href="#">link</a>
{% endif %}
```